# Query issue, insert and match

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID      food        MONTH   Cost
523     VEG         Jan     50.00 
523     HOT DOG     Feb     40.00 
523     VEG         Feb     55.00 
523     COOKIE      Feb     10.00 
984     VEG         Mar     60.00 
427                 Jan     15.00 
644     HOT DOG     Feb     35.00 
644     FRIES       Feb      2.00 
644     HOT DOG     Mar     40.00
```

I need to insert a column after food (food2) that shows Vegetable

```
where veg=Vegatable, HOT DOG=Hot Dog, COOKIE=Cookie,
```

in proper format(capital first letter), If not one of these three, hot dog, cookie, and vegatbale, it equals other

```
ID  Food    food2           MONTH   REVENUE
523 VEG     Vegetable       Jan           50.00 
523 HOT DOG Hot Dog         Feb           40.00 
523 VEG     Vegetable       Feb           55.00 
523 COOKIE  Cookie          Feb           10.00 
984 VEG     Vegetable       Mar           60.00 
427         Other           Jan           15.00 
644 HOT DOG Hot Dog         Feb           35.00 
644 FRIES   Other           Feb            2.00 
644 HOT DOG Hot Dog         Mar           40.00
```

Comment: Use a Case Expression `SELECT id, food, CASE WHEN food='VEG' THEN 'Vegetable WHEN food='HOT DOG' THEN 'Hot Dog' END as Food22, Month, Revenue FROM yourtable` ?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ID, 
       Food, 
       CASE WHEN Food = ‘VEG’ THEN ‘Vegetable’ 
            WHEN Food = ‘HOT DOG’ THEN ‘Hot Dog’ 
            WHEN Food = ‘COOKIE’ THEN ‘Cookie’ 
            ELSE ‘Other’ END AS Food2, 
       MONTH, 
       REVENUE
FROM MyTable
```